# Push timeout in Routing configuration / any alternate to hold work item with agent until presence status of that agent is back to available

Tags: service-cloud-console, omnichannel, skill-based-routing

Background : Using Skill based routing. When agent is OFFLINE on Omni Channel, new tickets will be reallocated directly if another agent is available.

Issue: Unfortunately, if you have a drop of internet, or someone simply change to OFFLINE, tickets are reassigned immediately based of agent's identified by salesforce.

Is there any way to hold the work item with agent for some definite amount of time before rerouting / stop that item from rerouting until the agent is back to available.

How does Push Time-Out (seconds) field on routing configuration work's if agent goes offline ?